# Knex Migration Error .spread() Not a function

Tags: knex.js

When running the command 'knex migrate:latest' in the terminal I am presented with this error...

```
➜  WebpackExpressKnexPackage git:(knexInit) ✗ knex migrate:latest
Using environment: development
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:127
      pending = initKnex(env).migrate.latest().spread(function(batchNo, log) {
                                               ^

TypeError: initKnex(...).migrate.latest(...).spread is not a function
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:127:48)
    at Command.listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Command.parseArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/commander/index.js:653:12)
    at Command.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/commander/index.js:475:21)
    at Liftoff.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:186:13)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:190:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:164:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:108:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:35:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:47:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

I've entirely removed all things Brew and NPM from my computer, reinstalled them and completely rewritten my server several times in the hopes of finding a solution, but at every corner I am presented with the same error, .spread() is not a function.

Here you can see that I'm running a current version of Knex.js:

```
➜  WebpackExpressKnexPackage git:(knexInit) ✗ knex -V
Knex CLI version:  0.14.2
Local Knex version:  0.21.16
```

I cannot, however, discover how to uninstall Knex-Cli:

```
➜  WebpackExpressKnexPackage git:(knexInit) ✗ npm uninstall --save knex
removed 32 packages and audited 714 packages in 2.558s
found 0 vulnerabilities

➜  WebpackExpressKnexPackage git:(knexInit) ✗ knex -V
Knex CLI version:  0.14.2
Local Knex version:  undefined
```

I came across a thread that mentioned it might be legacy Bluebird code, but that thread was closed before anyone could provide an answer. In the hopes that the problem is in Knex CLI, I've successfully uninstalled Knex, but can't remove Knex CLI.
I'm at a complete loss. I've learned a lot, but nothing that gets me past this wall. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running `npm uninstall -g knex`?

Comment: Kibertoad, yes, thank you, I have. That was one of my first attempts. I have attempted to entirely remove all things NPM from my machine before reinstalling. When I uninstall Knex, Knex CLI still remains. I dont know if the error is rooted in the cli or if it's somewhere else, I'm just scratching at anything now.

Comment: Judging by your log entry, here is where the local knex is:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js


You can try removing "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/knex/"

Comment: Here's an update. I have the problem with the .spread() function when I install the most current version of Knex.js (0.21.16). The problem appears to be in that package. However, when I install the second most recent version (0.18.0-next4) I no longer have any issues. Hopefully this problem will be addressed in future iterations of the Knex package.

Comment: This is not "second most recent" by far, this is just the last unstable release.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using .spread() function somewhere in your code? Newer knex dropped bluebird dependency and spread() is no longer available. Check UPGRADING.md file for migration guide.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding of the inner workings of my machine are limited. After four years of changing paths and installing/uninstalling/updating (and who really knows what other mistakes I've made; i.e., I had useless package.json files scattered all over the place), I came to the conclusion that I needed to start from scratch. I ended up completely factory resetting my machine without utilizing any backups and then reinstalling Homebrew and Node (and other libraries as I needed them) from the ground up. I'm not sure, but my theory is that my machine was so congested that it was somehow confusing itself. I can't say for sure that this was the problem, but the factory reset was an effective solution.

Thanks everyone for your input.